# Saving a date to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this problem with saving a date into a MySQL database.

I have this input field:

```
<input type="date" name="theDate" id="theDate" required></p>
```

Before I save it to the database I format the string to a date like this:

```
date('Y.m.d', strtotime($table['day']));
```

The database field is a **DATE** but it only saves `0000-00-00`.

When I echo out the date before saving it, it is correctly `2012-02-23`.

I hope anyone can tell me how this is done.

Comment: Quite simply, MySQL expects input as `Y-m-d`. Use that instead of `Y.m.d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date('Y.m.d', strtotime($table['day']));
```

outputs `2012.02.23` not `2012-02-23` ... you need

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($table['day']));
```

[See this section on MySQL Date and Time literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

Comment: thanks to both of you.
Sometimes the right answer is right in front of you but you need someone to point it out...
(i'm so ashamed right now)